# Find the complete integral of $(x+y)(p+q)^2 + (x-y)(p-q)^2=1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The question is:
Find the complete integral of $(x+y)(p+q)^2 + (x-y)(p-q)^2=1$.

I tried by Charpit's method.
On solving, I got  $\dfrac{dp}{2p²+2q²} = \dfrac{dq}{4pq}$.

Since it is a homogeneous equation, on further simplifying it,
 implies $1-(p/q)²=c/q$ , where $c$ is a constant.
But on putting the above value of $p$ in the given equation, it becomes messy and difficult to solve.

Here $p=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$  and  $q=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.
Is there a better way to approach this question?

Comment: What is the dependent variable?

Comment: Here p stands for ∂z/∂x, q stands for ∂z/∂y. Dependent variable is z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $\begin{cases}u=x+y\\v=x-y\end{cases}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}$

$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}-\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}$

$\therefore4u\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right)^2+4v\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}\right)^2=1$

$u\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right)^2+v\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}\right)^2=\dfrac{1}{4}$

It belongs to a PDE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fpde/fpde3212.pdf.

Comment: Thanks @doraemonpaul for the solution. It is really helpful..